# Create contacts in Exchange through EWS

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I'm new to Exchange and I would like to create a local contact and a group of contacts through Exchange Web Services (EWS).

It doesn't seem to have some methods to do that, or I don't find the precise function to do it in the following documentation: [Exchange Web Services (EWS) in Exchange 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

We use Exchange 2010 SP3.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems I can use the [ExchangeService.CreateItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.createitems(v=exchg.80).aspx) method and put some items in it, like [contacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.contact(v=exchg.80).aspx) or a [group of contacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.contactgroup(v=exchg.80).aspx).

From the [main documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

**Item Operations**
The Item operations provide access to items in the Exchange data store. By using these operations, a client application can create, update, delete, copy, get, move, and send items. The Item operations work on the following item types:

[...]

- **Contact Items**   Contact items are a set of properties that represent contacts that are located either in the Active Directory directory service or in private contact stores. It is important to note that, while these two types of contacts are similar in data content, they differ in the types of operations that you can perform on them.